# Functional Dependencies Inference Rules

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I have this Relation with these dependancies:

```
R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
Fd1: A → B,C,D
Fd2: A,D → E  
Fd3: E,F,G → H
Fd4: F → G,H
```

My question is: there is a redundant dependency in this set and I want to know how the process of identifying this redundancy goes. The answer according to the solutions is FD3 however I have no idea how this was achieved: could anyone explain this?

Comment: Hi, I see you were new to SO when you asked this question. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to remove any redundant dependency is to find a ***minimal cover***. To find *minimal cover* -

- **First** ensure singleton right-hand side (RHS)
- **Second** remove any extraneous left-hand side (LHS) attribute
- **Third** remove any redundant functional dependency

**For example:** In your relation R -

**First** ensure singleton RHS. So now we have -
A->B
A->C
A->D
A->E
EFG->H
F->G
F->H

**Second** we remove any extraneous LHS attributes. There is only one FD which has more then one LHS attribute (***EFG**->H*). If **E<sup>+</sup>**(*E-closure*) has **F** we can remove **F** from the FD and vice-versa. Here F<sup>+</sup> has **G** so we remove **G**.

**Third** Now we can check for redundant dependencies! To check that for each FD (*X->Y*) we remove that dependency and see if we can still get to *Y* from *X*. For example in our case when we hide FD ***EF***->H we see we can still get to **H** from **F** using the last FD (*F->H*). Therefore we can remove the FD ***EF***->H. So now we have -
A->B
A->C
A->D
A->E
F->G
F->H

This is a *minimal cover*.

**Lastly,** we can combine FD with same LHS so we finally have -
A->BCDE
F->GH

This should be your final answer which will have no redundant dependencies. In your case since you have to **choose one** of the given FD's as redundant then **FD3** will be the answer on comparing with what we have reduced it to.

Comment: one of the Singleton RHS should be **EFG->H**